# How to fetch values using AMPScript from different data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I have a question regarding AMPScript. My Data Extensions are attached in the link at end of this question(For reference). I want to send personalised email adding product name.

```
%%[ 
var @productname
set @productname = lookup("Products","product_name","product_id",[product_id]) 
]%%

<h1> You just purchased : %%= v(@productname) =%%
```

Please can someone correct me ?

Also, should I link these tables in Data designer ???
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmq1p.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to link the data extensions in Data Designer, in order to use `Lookup` function.

There are few issues in your code. I assume you get product_ID from your sendable data extension? If this is the case, I will start by declaring it using `attributevalue`. You will then be able to reference it in the lookup call. Also, you need to get rid of the spaces where you want to print your product name. This should work:

```
%%[ 
set @orderid = attributevalue("order_id")
set @orderrows = LookupRows("orders","order_id", @orderid)
set @orderRowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)
if @orderRowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @orderRowCount do
set @row = row(@orderRowCount, @i)
set @productid = field(@row,"product_id")
set @productname = lookup("Products","product_name","product_id",@productid) 
]%%

<h1>You just purchased : %%=v(@productname)=%%</h1>

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No order rows found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But what if my product_id is not in the Sendable data extension. How can I modify the code to display the product_name?

Comment: Well - it must be somewhere in the context of the send, @Guest17. How would we otherwise be able to know which product to lookup the name for?

Comment: yes you are right, I got your point. I am a bit confused, I am referring to this table-https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmq1p.png. Can I identify which product customer has bought by Order_id?

Comment: @Guest17 I digged more into your data model. You need to lookup the order rows for the recipient, and for each row lookup the product name. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks you very much for this answer. This is what I exactly wanted